# Embedding Youtube/Vimeo vids in Sencha Touch not playing with Blackberry OS 6

Tags: youtube-api, sencha-touch, vimeo, blackberry-os6

I can't seem to get Vimeo or Youtube videos that are embedded with HTML5 embed code to play on the Blackberry 6 devices. The video just sits there, with the spinner spinning. Checked with multiple Blackberries, all of which work fine on Vimeo's website and Youtube's website, and other website embedding said content.

Sample code for the Youtube video below. Vimeo code is the same, with different URL.

**Edit:** this is through the browser, not web works.

```
function(options) {


    var details = new Ext.Panel({

        autoRender: true,
        floating: true,
        modal: true,
        centered: true,
        scroll: false,
        hideOnMaskTap: true,
        dockedItems: [{

            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            title: '',
            items: [{

                text: 'Close',
                handler: function() {

                    details.update('');
                    details.hide('pop');    

                    }
                }]
        }],
        listeners: {
            deactivate: function (p) {
                p.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
    );

    details.update('<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+options.data.id+'?showinfo=0&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    details.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you granted access to the domains in your [webworks configuration file](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/access_element_834677_11.html) like this?

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://www.youtube.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://www.vimeo.com"/>
```

Comment: This is a web app through the browser, not an installed webworks app.